# How do I export JIRA issues to xls?

Tags: excel, jira, wget

As title says. I'm trying to export JIRA issues to a xls file through my command line.

this is what I'm entering:

```
wget -O export.xls https://myjiraurl.com/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-all-fields/10300/SearchRequest-10300.xls?tempMax=1000
```

But I keep getting this error

```
Resolving myjiraurl.com (myjiraurl.com)... 10.64.80.92
Connecting to myjiraurl.com (myjiraurl.com)|10.64.80.92|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify myjiraurl.com's certificate, issued by â€˜/C=US/O=MyCorporation/CN=Intel Intranet Basic Issuing CA 2Bâ€™:
Self-signed certificate encountered.
To connect to myjiraurl.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

I've also tried adding

```
 &os_username=<myuserid>&os_password=<mypassword>
```

how it still gives me the same thing. I've tried directly plugging the url into the address bar and it exports a xls file back to be just fine. tips?

Comment: did you read the final line of the error message? fiddling with url parameters is pointless...

Comment: yes I tried that and got a 400 bad request

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
wget --user=userid --password=secret --no-check-certificate -O export.xls "https://myjiraurl.com/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-all-fields/10300/SearchRequest-10300.xls?tempMax=1000"
```